# Rings | Homomorphisms | Units

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, inverse

### Question

Show that if $f :R\rightarrow S$ is a homomorphism, and if $a$ is a unit of $R$, then $f(a)$ is
a unit of $S$. Show, in fact, that $f(a^{−1}) = f(a)^{−1}$ for any unit $a$ of $R$.

### Attempt

Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a homomorphism. Then

$$ f(a)=f(a\cdot 1_R)=f(a)f(1_R),$$

so

$$ f(1_R)=\frac{f(a)}{f(a)}=1_S, $$

which is me trying to show why $(6)$ holds:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Consequently, we then have that,

$$ f(a\cdot a^{-1})=f(a)f(a^{-1})=f(1_R)=1_S, $$

so it is then easy to see that because $f(a)f(a^{-1})=1_S$, then $f(a)$ is a unit in $S$. Furthermore, by the same equality

$$ f(a^{-1})=\frac{1_S}{f(a)}=f(a)^{-1}, $$

as needed.

Comment: I'll add the pictures in a moment. Just wait.

Comment: It's best not to write fractions, as rings are not necessarily commutative.  When you write something like $\frac{a}{b} = c \in R$, do you mean that $a = bc$ or $a = cb$?

Comment: For you, any element of $S$ is invertible?

Comment: @Sigur What do you mean "for me"?

Comment: Just to be clear to future onlookers, $R$ and $S$ are rings.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh, I mean, if you are considering this since you wrote 'a ring for which every element...'

Comment: What is $f(a)/f(a)$? Does $f(a)$ have an inverse?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** if $a\in R$ is a unity then you can write $1_R=a\cdot b$. Use the fact that $f(1_R)=1_S$ and compute $f(a\cdot b)$.

Comment: That's what I've done.

Answer (score 2):

You've got something of the right idea, here, but are off in a few details. I assume that your rings are abelian groups under addition, monoids under multiplication, with multiplication being left- and right-distributive over addition. I further assume your definition of a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ requires $1_R\mapsto 1_S.$ Let me know if my assumptions are correct.

Now, given those assumptions, we know for any unit $a\in R$ that $$1_S=f(1_R)=f(aa^{-1})=f(a)f(a^{-1}),$$ and likewise, $$1_S=f(a^{-1})f(a).$$ Thus, indeed, we have that $f(a)$ is a unit of $S$ and $f(a)^{-1}=f(a^{-1}).$

---

**Added**: The assumptions that I made above are actually necessary. Without them, the proposition is *false*.

On the one hand, if we only require a ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$ to satisfy $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\quad\text{and}\quad f(xy)=f(x)f(y)\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ for all $x,y\in R$, then let's consider $R=S=\Bbb Z$, and let $f:R\to S$ be given by $f(n)=0$ for all $n.$ Then $-1$ is a unit of $R$, but $f(-1)=0$ is not a unit of $S$, but $f$ is a ring homomorphism by this definition. This shows that without requiring $1_R\mapsto 1_S$, the proposition fails.

Now, suppose we don't require that a ring be a monoid under multiplication. (The even integers are then a ring, for example.) The most we can require in general, then, is that ring homomorphisms $f$ on $R$ satisfy $(\clubsuit)$, which we already saw wasn't enough.

Comment: How is the last part true?

Comment: The last part is true because $$f(a^{-1})f(a)=1_S=f(a)f(a^{-1}),$$ so $f(a^{-1})$ is the multiplicative inverse of $f(a)$.

Comment: Ahg! Yes! Sorry... Thank you so much, Cameron Buie.

Comment: How are monoids and rings related?

Comment: That depends on your definition of rings. A monoid is a set with an associative operation that has an identity associated with it. Rings are monoids under their multiplication operation if (and only if) we require that they have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: I see, so what if I want to show that the identity function is the only homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Note that any element of $\Bbb Q$ can be written in the form $n^{-1}m$ for some integers $m,n$ with $n\ne0$. By the above proposition (and homomorphism properties), we have $$f(n^{-1}m)=f(n)^{-1}f(m).$$ All that's left is to show that $f(k)=k$ for all integers $k$. I leave that to you.